# Return rows where one column is consistent but another changes within a time period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to find when a computer jumps from one access point to another and am capturing the data in a dbase. I am capturing the data every hour so the pc name will come up multiple times, but the ap will only change when the pc has switched from one to another. I am needing a sample query to return.

I only want to return a line when the ap has changed on a computer within the last 12 hours.

I tried selecting distinct of both fields, and then parsing them out, but I believe there has to be a better way.

An example table would look like:

1    PC1 AP1 Time

2    PC2 AP1 Time

3    PC3 AP2 Time

4    PC4 AP2 Time

5    PC5 AP3 Time

6    PC1 AP1 Time

7    PC2 AP2 Time

8    PC3 AP2 Time

9    PC4 AP2 Time

10   PC5 AP3 Time

So the only returned information should be about PC2 in this example as it is the only unit that changed APs, so I would get those two rows (2 and 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()`.  In standard SQL, this looks like:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(app) over (partition by computer order by time) as prev_app
      from t
     ) t
where prev_app <> app and
      time > current_datetime - interval '12 hour';
```

Date/time functionality is notoriously dependent on the database you are using, so the syntax for your database may be a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

With EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where computername = t.computername and ap <> t.ap 
  and time between dateadd(hour, -12, t.time) and dateadd(hour, 12, t.time)
)
```